# Set command-line local variable

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, variables

How can I set a variable that only the current command line sees?

So that

`:let s:one = 1 | echo s:one` prints `1`

but running two commands

`:let s:one = 1`
`:echo s:one`

errors `E121: Undefined variable: s:one`.

In the end I would like to remap to a command line that uses a temporary variable, without overriding or polluting any potential other user variables.

Comment: Could you explain why the first solution is not good enough? Where will the script will be defined: 1. in a one line mapping, 2. in a script file? How much persistent must the variable be: 1. in the call, 2. in the buffer lifetime, 3. in the Vim lifetime

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I get `Illegal variable name: s:one` when I try the first solution. The variable should only be as persistent as the call. I'm just defining a mapping like this in my vimrc `xnoremap <silent> il :<C-u>let s:one ...`

Comment: Do we need a `gensym` ?? Typically you use a unique prefix based on the plugin name or your initials or something.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't know what gensym is

Comment: In Lisps and Schemes it gives you a guaranteed unique symbol

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I could propose:

```
function! Variable(...)
  if a:0
    let x = a:1
  else
    let x = 0
  endif
  function! Set(...) closure
    if a:0
      let x = a:1
    endif
    return x
  endfunction
  return funcref('Set')
endfunction
```

With this `Variable` function you can create a variable that don't clutter the global workspace:

```
let X=Variable(4) " Initialize X to 4
call X(7) " Change X to 7
echo X() " Get the value of X
```

Comment: If "X" exists and is a variable then it will get overwritten by a funcref. So it is not a valid solution, I think.

Comment: You are right :-) I move the problem from variables to functions but the clutter problem remains :-|

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that a simple "echo" is not the extent of what you want to do with the assigned value.

But addressing only what is in your question...   why not go to the shell for this?

```
:!one=1; echo $one
```

If your larger plan can still work in the shell, then you simply capture it right below the current line with a leading `:r` :

```
:r !one1; echo $one
```

###### If on windows...

OS limitations here require delayed variable expansion

(which is the `/v:on` option to cmd.exe):

```
:r !cmd /v:on /c "set one=1 & echo \!one\!"
```

(escaping to prevent previous-command-substitution, see `:h :!`)

If you add the cmd option to your `'shellcmdflag'` setting, then it's just:

```
:r !set one=1 & echo \!one\!
```